# When would the boolen variable turn true?

Tags: apex

Class :

```
    public class insertobjectcontroller
    {
        public boolean initialized{get;set;}
        public Account acc{get;set;}
        public insertobjectcontroller(){
          initialized = false;
        }
        public void unit()
        {
            if(!initialized)
            { 
                acc = new Account();
                acc.name ='blog Account';
                insert acc;
                initialized = true;        
            }
        }
    }
```

Page :

```
    <apex:page controller="insertobjectcontroller">
    <apex:form >
    <apex:actionfunction name="doInit" action="{!unit}" rerender="allpanel"/>
    {!initialized}

    <script>   
      window.onload = function() {
          doInit();
          alert('comesssss');
      };
    </script>
    </apex:form>
    </apex:page>
```

When would the boolen variable **initialized** turn true ?

Comment: Please elaborate. What do you want to achieve? What is your usecase? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @UweHeim -  I need to display when variable - initialized is changing to true.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `unit` method to be called at the start of the process you can call it from the Apex constructor or using the [apex:page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_page.htm) action:

```
<apex:page controller="insertobjectcontroller" action="{!unit}">
```

As you have it coded, the `unit` method is called after the page has loaded so `initialized` turns `true` in the controller at that point. But you will not see the value change in the page because the `rerender` ID does not exist so the HTML will not change.

Note that by assigning to `window.onload` you are replacing other handling code that may already be present (e.g. code added by Visualforce).